# VSTO get left and top coordinates of pointer postion

Tags: vsto, office-addins

i want to get the left and top coordinates of the **Active Cell** in Excel and the same for the pointer position in Word so that i can insert image in that position specified by the user.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert() in excel and Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture in word will insert picture at selection and active cell.

However to get x,y information you can use following api

**word**

```
wordAppliaction.Selection.get_Information(WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)

wordAppliaction.Selection.get_Information(WdInformation.wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
```

**In excel**
it can be tricky to get coordinates precisely you can try with

```
Range.Top and Range.Left
```